# Woocommerce archive-products.php show subcategories and products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories

I need help with the archive-products.php Page please. In the Customizer I added "subcategories & products" - that's good so far but now I would like to make a "
" between the subcategories and the products so that not all is in the same row but I do not know how I can do that.

I found content-product-cat.php which will show the subcategories with "li" Tags, so there is no possibility to add a "
" because it will added after every entry which is not my goal. I would like to add it between the last subcategory entry and the first product entry.

Can someone please help me?

Currently my archive-product.php looks like this:

```
if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_all_notices - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

    woocommerce_product_loop_start();

    if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();

            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        }
    }

    woocommerce_product_loop_end();

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
} else {
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
     *
     * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
}
```

Thanks,
Fabian